# How does an antenna work?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-engineering, dipole, antennas

I'm looking for a model of an antenna that would explain how it works an in particular where the values of impedance like 36.5 ohms come from. I've tried looking but everything i found was overly pragmatic and only explained what one should consider when using an antenna, not the behavior itself. I've tried doing my own derivation, modeling a monopole antenna as a transmission line open at one end and with the antenna feedpoint at the other, forced by an external electric field $E(t)$:

$$C\dfrac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} t} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d} i}{\mathrm{d} x}$$
$$L\dfrac{\mathrm{d} i}{\mathrm{d} t} = E(t) + \dfrac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} x}$$
$$i(h, t) = 0$$
where $h$ is the length of the antenna and $u(0, t)$ and $i(0, t)$ are the voltage and current at the feedpoint. This model however doesn't account for the energy loss due to radiation and I don't know how to change it. How does an antenna work?

Comment: Bunch of downvotes, sigh. It's a messy, practical problem physics professors don't like to talk about. Jackson's Electrodynamics covers this approximately (with a fair amount of handwaving).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, the telegrapher's equation is sufficient to model radiation damping. The equations in their standard form is rather:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal C\partial_t u+\partial_x i &= 0 & \mathcal L\partial_t i+\partial_x u &= 0
\end{align}
$$
with $\mathcal C$ the capacitance per unit length and $\mathcal L$ the inductance per unit length. You'll be imposing $u(x=0)=v(t)$, and for simplicity, you can assume that the the spatial domain is $\mathbb R_+$, so you don't need to make any assumption on the end of the line.

To find the impedance of the line, you just need to solve for $i(x=0)=j(t)$, which by linearity and time invariance, you know will be of the form of a convolution product:
$$
j = g*v
$$
with $g$ the admittance of the line. To find $g$, you just need to solve for the impulse response, $v=\delta(t)$.

At this stage, the problem is still ill posed since you need to specify the initial conditions on the fields $u(t=0),i(t=0)$. The natural approach is to look for causal solutions so that $u(t<0)=i(t<0)=0$. You can now solve the general problem and find (with $H$ the Heaviside function):
$$
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= v(t-x/c) & i(x,t) &= Gv(t-x/c) \\
c &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mathcal L\mathcal C}} & G &= \sqrt{\frac{\mathcal C}{\mathcal L}}
\end{align}
$$
so you recover the impedance of the line:
$$
j = Gv\\
R = \sqrt{\frac{\mathcal L}{\mathcal C}}
$$
Since it is positive, you have dissipation. This is consistent with the conservation of energy. Due to causality, you only have waves propagating to the right, extracting energy from the source. Mathematically, you have the local law of conservation of energy:
$$
\partial_t\left(\frac{\mathcal C}{2}u^2+\frac{\mathcal L}{2}i^2\right)+\partial_x(ui)=0
$$
Integrating over all of space and since the fields are initially zero and signals travel at a finite speed, $u(\infty)=i(\infty)=0$ so:
$$
vj = \frac{d}{dt}\int \left(\frac{\mathcal C}{2}u^2+\frac{\mathcal L}{2}i^2\right)dx
$$
i.e. the input power equals the variation of energy in the line. This power is positive because the energy travels to the right and is not reflected back to the source.

The key is causality, had you taken anticausal solutions, you would have found the opposite impedance. The same underlying principle is behind the vacuum impedance and the radiation impedance of realistic antennae. You can adapt the telegrapher's equation to model the EM field, by assuming invariance by translation along the $y,z$ axis (the spatial domain is now $\mathbb R$), from Maxwell's equations:
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_x E_y &= -\mu_0\partial_t H_z & -\partial_x H_z &= j_y+\epsilon_0\partial_t E_y
\end{align}
$$
I used $H = \frac{1}{\mu_0}B$ to make the analogy
$$
\begin{align}
u&\to E_y & i&\to H_z\\
\mathcal C&\to \epsilon_0 & \mathcal L&\to \mu_0
\end{align}
$$
If $j_x=i(t)\delta(x)$, then:
$$
\begin{align}
E_y &= -\frac{R}{2}i(t-|x|/c) & H_z &= -\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{2}i(t-|x|/c) \\
c &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}} & R = \sqrt\frac{\mu_0}{\epsilon_0}
\end{align}
$$
You therefore get that the impedance of the vacuum is $R/2$. Intuitively, the $1/2$ comes from the two possible directions of the waves.

Similarly, you have Poynting's theorem:
$$
\partial_t\left(\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}E_y^2+\frac{\mu_0}{2}H_z^2\right)+\partial_x\left(E_yH_z\right)+j_yE_y=0
$$
The flux at infinity is still zero, so you get that energy is being accumulated in the field due to the negative source term $j_yE_y$.

A more realistic model for an antenna would be to rather use spherical (resp. cylindrical) symmetry rather than plane symmetry. You recover an effective 1D waveguide, only the equations are a bit more complicated due to the geometry and involve spherical (usual) Bessel functions. This will modify the geometric prefactor of the radiation resistance.

Btw, you can trace back this phenomena in a simple LC circuit:
$$
L\ddot q +\frac{1}{C}q = v
$$
You naturally have a resonant frequency and impedance:
$$
\begin{align}
\omega &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}} & R &= \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}
\end{align}
$$
The admittance is:
$$
Y = \frac{1}{R}H(t)\cos(\omega t)
$$
so as you can see, it is basically $1/R$ for small times. Intuitively, causality "wants" to dissipate energy, but due to interferences the input power is not always positive. This is also visible in a finite length transmission line. When you take let the length go to infinity, you let the reflection come back in infinite time, so you only witness the initial times where you only have dissipation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can an infinite length antenna help understand something like a quarter wave antenna and how can this model describe reception of em waves? I don't think I understand.

Comment: Oh ok I understand better your initial attempt. The issue is that to understand an antenna, you need to include the surrounding medium to derive the radiation impedance. If you just have an antenna all by itself like what you tried with your finite waveguide, the energy will just stay in the antenna and not radiate away. In my waveguide model, the antenna is essentially the first capacitor, the rest represents the vacuum.